# Java AppEngine: fetch 2 urls in HTTPS

Tags: java, google-app-engine, https

I'm trying to fetch data of some https website from google appengine (java).
There are two step: log-in then fetch data from another page.

In the dev server, I complete this two steps successfully, with very basic java code (URL and HttpConnection, POST data).

When deployed on appengine, step 1 is ok, but step 2 fails.

I should add that I'm using two different http connections objects, but as it is working in dev server, I told myself that there was some cookie/session stuffs to keep the connection between the two calls.

But it fails in appengine context, so I'm wondering if it can't be related to my browser and https certificates?

Comment: "Fails" how? Please provide more detail.

Comment: it fails like the "user" is not connected. The response is the "not-logged" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built an application to the Facebook hosted on AppEngine.

And to make https requests i'm using the URLFetchService:

```
String request = "https://graph.facebook.com/194652357227159?access_token=Aj2h4df...";
URL url = new URL(request);
URLFetchService urlFetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
HTTPResponse resp =  urlFetchService.fetch(new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.GET, FetchOptions.Builder.doNotValidateCertificate()));
```

Hope that helps.